# spacing links using minimal CSS and without using tables

Tags: html, css

If I use the following CSS:

```
#container A{width:72px;height:50px;margin:12px}
```

and the following HTML:

```
<div ID="container"> <a href="something">Something</a> <a href="something">Something</a> <a href="something">Something</a> </div>
```

I can make links spaced out nicely.

However, if I remove this CSS:

```
#container A{width:72px;height:50px;margin:12px}
```

In my browser, instead of seeing the links as:

```
Something Something Something
```

I see:

```
SomethingSomethingSomething
```

I even tried using this HTML instead:

```
<div ID="container"><a href="something">Something</a>&nbsp;<a href="something">Something</a>&nbsp;<a href="something">Something</a></div>
```

but the `&nbsp;` wouldn't even do the trick.

Yes I understand that I can apply javascript later, but I need a solution for users with javascript disabled and I need my CSS minimized as much as possible because my site uses adsense and I read that the closer to the first byte my adsense code is at, the more money I could make, and making the CSS as external is not an option.

Is there a way I can solve this without having to resort to using an HTML table?

Comment: ok this is a strange behaviour, can you make sure there are spaces in the source code? what does the developer tools inspector show? are the anchor tags floated? what is their display value?

Comment: Any other CSS affecting anchor tags?

Comment: Its #container a. Not "#container  A"

Comment: @JinuKurian CSS selectors are case insensitive. `a` and `A` are equivilent.  To clarify, ID and classes are case sensitive, but tag names are not.

Comment: I can see &nbsp; is working fine in chrome without css, in which browser you are seeing this issue?

Comment: I suspect that you have `a {float:left; }` in your CSS somewhere.

Comment: I'm using opera 11.64

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is correct. Both the CSS or simply placing a space () between each tag will work. Something else is causing the rending issues.
2. You should minimize your CSS for page load times.  While high page load times can cause your site to receive less conversions, the closer your Adsense code is to the top of your page has absolutely nothing to do with how much revenue you'll make.